# Change color of CircularProgressIndicator and LinearProgressIndicator

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to change color of `CircularProgressIndicator` and `LinearProgressIndicator` to accent color with `theme` of `MaterialApp` globally?
(In previous version of flutter the default color was accent color and after upgrading flutter it's primary color)

Try the following code in dart pad, I want to change color of progress globally without chaining `primarySwatch` if possible

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        accentColor: Colors.red,
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think its not even primary color, but the default blue color at least for me.

Comment: The color changed when you change primary color

Comment: Strange. For me it doesn't. I am on Flutter stable channel 2.2.2 .

Comment: @WebMaster yes it would change as it is controlled from the theme's accent color. Check my answer

Comment: @JigarPatel try setting `primarySwatch`

Comment: @WebMaster, it seems you are right. Earlier it was using directly the `accentColor`. Now it seems to use `primaryColor` from `colorScheme`, so `primarySwatch` must be affecting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By wrapping with `ProgressIndicatorTheme` we can customize the color of `CircularProgressIndicator` and `LinearProgressIndicator` globally